# How can I make this API call from my Nodejs program?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, heroku, backend

A member of my team developed this API where you send some numeric values and it gives you back a probability. He deployed it in `Heroku` and sent me the task of connecting it with our backend, you can make the call from cmd like this:

```
curl -d "{\"Values\":[[value1,value 2,value 3,value 4,value 5]]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://apibc1.herokuapp.com/predict
```

And it will work just like intended, but to be honest I don't know how to make this call in my server file, I'm trying to use the request package in Node but I keep getting the invalid URI error on my logs. An example of the API working from cmd:
[image]
And this is what happens when I make the same call in my server.js file:
[image]

Comment: I have checked the API in Postman, it is throwing an internal server error `500`. Can you share the API docs like what is the input and queryparams?

Comment: It'd be helpful to show your NodeJS code. It appears you used the JSON as your URL (and appended the actual URL to the end of that) in your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a working curl you can import it into postman and generate a working code sample for a lot of languages.

1. Import the curl request

[image]

2. Then click the code button on the right

[image]

3. and select a language/framework option from the dropdown

[image]